# Showing an action sheet in a view with hidden tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, show, uitabbar, uiactionsheet

I have a view controller within a `UITabBarController`, but I made its `UITabBar` hidden while in the view of such view controller because of the needs of my app. My question is: when showing an `UIActionSheet` from this view controller, should I call `[actionSheet showInView:self.view]` or `[actionSheet showFromTabBar:tabBar]`?

Thanks in advance